# Justify-center in FlexBox causes items in scrollable div to get clipped

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, flexbox, tailwind-css

```
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [numItems, setNumItems] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="w-full">
      <div className="flex p-5 align-center w-full flex-col">
        <div className="flex justify-center">
          <button
            className="border-red-500 border-2 m-2 p-2"
            onClick={() => {
              addItems("Item " + (numItems + 1));
              setNumItems(numItems + 1);
            }}
          >
            Add Item
          </button>
        </div>

        <div className="flex flex-nowrap justify-center align-center p-2 overflow-x-auto border-2 border-blue-700">
          {items.map((item) => (
            <div className="m-2 p-2 border-red-800 border-2 flex-shrink-0" key={item}>
              <h1>{item}</h1>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  function addItems(item) {
    setItems([...items, item]);
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

I am using Tailwind css with React.js

In the component above, I have a button that simply adds divs horizontally to a flexbox that automatically scrolls. The issue is, I am not able to add the divs from the center i.e if I add the justify-center or justify-content: center; in normall css, the items in the beginning get clipped off. How can I keep adding items indefinitely, without losing the items and maintaining the ability to scroll?

Codepen link : https://codepen.io/vineet192/pen/jOGZQZE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your snippet a little bit, to make it work.

Basically the clipping was because of the overflow + center.

```
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [numItems, setNumItems] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="w-full">
      <div className="flex p-5 align-center w-full flex-col">
        <div className="flex justify-center">
          <button
            className="border-red-500 border-2 m-2 p-2"
            onClick={() => {
              addItems("Item " + (numItems + 1));
              setNumItems(numItems + 1);
            }}
          >
            Add Item
          </button>
        </div>

        <div className="flex flex-nowrap justify-center align-center p-2 overflow-x-hidden border-2 border-blue-700">
          <div className='flex overflow-x-auto'>
          {items.map((item) => (
            <div
              className="m-2 p-2 border-red-800 border-2 flex-shrink-0"
              key={item}
            >
              <h1>{item}</h1>
            </div>
          ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  function addItems(item) {
    setItems([...items, item]);
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```